# Train from EU to Kaliningrad

Tags: trains, russia, borders

I'm an EU citizen, and I'd like to travel to Kaliningrad. I like trains, and there's a direct from St. Petersburg to Kaliningrad, with stops in Vilnius and Kaunas.

However, neither the Russian railways not Lithuanian railways show Lithuania-Kalinigrad connections.

Can I buy a ticket for this connection? And are there any trains to and from Poland? I don't mind getting off at the border and getting on the next train on the other side.

This map suggests that the leftmost line to Poland is operational:[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Enthusiast's Guide to Travelling the Railways of Europe](https://egtre.info/wiki/Border_Crossings:_Poland_-_Russia), the Poland-Kaliningrad connection was last used regularly in 2012 for passenger services. It was rumoured that it was going to be brought back for the 2018 World Cup but nothing materialised, ultimately.

However, the [Lithuania-Kaliningrad](https://egtre.info/wiki/Border_Crossings:_Lithuania_-_Russia) border, according to the same website, DOES get passenger trains, worked from Kybartai station on the Lithuanian side. I don't know whether or not there are through trains still, or if you would have to change there. They are apparently worked by [Russian Railways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Railways), so I imagine they would have to be booked through there.

Comment: Thanks, Russian Railways do sell Vilnius - Kaliningrad tickets, which is great. If local trains run to Mamonovo (Russia), and then from Braniewo (Poland), one could walk the 13km road between them. It seems to have a pedestrian sidewalk.

Comment: Same for Bagrationovsk (Russia) to Bartoszyce (Poland)

Comment: @MrMartin I believe you can't cross the Russian border on foot.

Answer (score 5):

Cheers from Kaliningrad!

At the moment - Vilnius is the only option available. Check this blog for details about tickets: http://kaliningradguide.com/category/transportation/train/

And well, there also some extreme options from EU with a connection in Moscow or Minsk if you are a train enthusiast. There are plenty of bus and flight options to travel from EU to Kaliningrad region for a regular tourist.

A year ago we had some successful local trains test runs from Gdansk and Klaipeda. But this initiative failed in the end, can't expect any changes here soon.

Note that you can't cross the border with Poland at Braniewo and Bartoszyce on foot. You will have to take a bus or hitchhike.

Anyway, feel free to contact me regarding any questions on visiting Kaliningrad. Will be happy to assist you with that.

Comment: I would expect hitch-hiking to be difficult in this case.

Comment: I've met some travelers with such experience. And crossed the russian border this way couple of times myself. So, it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your question about links to Poland the only route which the DB train finder offers is via Minsk. You leave at 1403 on the Moscow train and change at Minsk at 0023 with 20 minutes before the sleeper to Warsaw arriving at 0755. There is a later train which also travels overnight but is not a sleeper. You would need to check if you need a transit visa for Belarus.

Comment: Belarus does not border Kaliningrad.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend traveling this route by train. It is much better to travel by bus. Bus is faster, cheaper, far more comfortable.

Take Ecolines from Kaliningrad to Vilnius (about 12 euros):

https://ecolines.net/international/en/bus/kaliningrad-vilnius%28bus-station%29

Take LuxExpress from Vilnius to St. Petersburg (about 50 euros):

https://luxexpress.eu/en

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I'm not going to St Petersburg, and in the end, I took the bus to Klaipeda, and then across the Curonian Spit to Kaliningrad

Comment: That's a beautiful route and probably the most laid back border crossing anywhere in Russia. Depending on the time of year, there are wild foxes, rabbits, and deer running around right at the border crossing.

Comment: A lot depends on what kind of trip you are planning to make.

Direct connection between Vilnius and Kaliningrad is available, bus is cheaper, trains - more comfortable. Travel time similar.

But if you plan to visit other places on your way, consider bus connections in Klaipeda, Palanga, Kaunas, Nida, Druskininkai, Taurage, Siauliai, Marijampole, Kybartai.

p.s. Sovetsk provides you with an interesting option to enter Russia on foot. Some travelers are interested in such experience as well.