# Travel to Kaliningrad by train with E-Visa

Tags: paperwork, russia, e-visas, kaliningrad, austrian-citizens

Since July 2019, there is an e-Visa valid for Kaliningrad, available to Austrians amongst others. The application website mentions [two possible rail border crossings](https://electronic-vissa.kdmid.ru/klgd_checkpoint_en.html), one in Mamonovo and one in Sovetsk. [RZD mentions restrictions](https://pass.rzd.ru/main-pass/public/en) on their website concerning rail travel to Kaliningrad and Leningrad oblasts when on e-Visa, and warns of some specific checkpoints where the e-Visa is invalid (Buslovskaya, Vyborg, Ivangorod, Nesterov).

Does anybody know whether there is a train connection crossing the Sovetsk border checkpoint currently, and if it actually is possible to take it with the e-Visa?

I was not able to find one with RZD or other train providers in Russia, but I have found that there seem to have been connections from Klaipeda at some point.

Alternatively, if there are none, is it possible to take one of the trains on the Vilnius-Kaliningrad route via the Kybartai checkpoint? It is not listed as allowed by KDMID, but not disallowed by RZD either.

A friend of mine took the train via Kybartai in June 2019, with the [European Games exception](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138769/95392), and could cross successfully, with the guards taking their time to check his ticket, and mentioning something about "Futbol".

[Train from EU to Kaliningrad](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130901/train-from-eu-to-kaliningrad) seems very related, but from the time before  e-Visas were introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**E-visa isn't valid for trains, unfortunately.** Official reason - no mobile scanners available, as the border check is done right on the train. Which doesn't make a lot of sense, as basically the same system was operational during the FIFA World Cup 2018.

There are plenty of bus options available. And even a unique option to cross the border on foot. :-D Cheers from Kaliningrad. Let me know if you need any help with information on visiting Kaliningrad.

p.s. Maybe the upcoming UEFA Euro 2020 will make some positive changes in this matter. Or recently announced plans to expand this e-visa scheme for all Russian Territory in 2021.

Comment: Yes, I mean my friend managed to cross last June but they took his passport and I guess left to their office and called their superiors or something. The train had to wait and I think the delay was about half an hour - I understand if they don't want to disrupt the "domestic" train for regular passengers until they have mobile scanners!

Where is that foot crossing, if I may ask? Bus is surely more comfortable but crossing by foot would be the next best thing to train...

Comment: It's a long story... 
In 2018 Russia and Belarus made an agreement, for visa-free transit for fans via Belarus. in exchange for the same for European Games 2019 in Belarus. So fans could travel via Russia.

Technically - the same procedure as e-visas. But for some reason, we have this mess... same story in Saint Pete, as I heard before.

Comment: On Foot Crossing: Gusev/Goldap, Sovetsk/Panemune, Chernyshevskoye/Kybartai.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I am familiar with the fan id and the similar program for travelling to Belarus via Russia for European Games last year. I didn't manage it unfortunately but the friend I wanted to travel with did and went to Belarus via Kaliningrad by train from Vilnius and then plane to Minsk :)

Comment: @NickKharchenko Of course they have mobile devices, at least on the Allegro train. The problem is they cannot access the e-visa verification system on those mobile devices

Comment: Yeah, probably software, legal or political reasons, not hardware.

Just checked the news: Russian Railroad stated, that they are working on that issue. But except technical questions, it "depends on traffic and international relations with neighbor countries." (c)

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot enter Kaliningrad by train, as the only operational railway checkpoint (Chernyshevskoye) is **not** listed as an approved port of entry.

RZD has no say in this, and so no authority to allow or prohibit it.

So you need to enter by air or bus/car

Comment: It's interesting they only list non-operational rail crossings as allowed. Are there plans to have trains run there for the future that you know of?

Comment: @JakeDot Nope, not that I know of.

Comment: They listed non-passenger-operational rail crossing, for cargo trains, etc.

p.s. The only train travel option available is Vilnius - Kaliningrad connection, this will require a regular visa. Nothing new exected so far. :-(